# How do I remotely start a mini-PC?

Tags: wake-up

I'm looking for a simple way to wake up a remote PC. It has Windows 11. My looking around has found:

1. Wake On Lan programs that I can't get to work.
2. A smart plug and having the PC start on resumption of power
3. Alexa. Supposedly this works, have not had a chance to try.

Anything else? I'm not technically smart to do things like Apache Guacamole.

Once I get it started, how do I get past the initial blue screen so I can get to the log in PIN screen?

Comment: What do you mean "wake up a PC remotely"? Do you literally mean Wake from Sleep, because some of your solutions would be to power it up from a power off state? If so, that is what Wake on LAN is intended for... As far as getting past the PIN code, you don't without disabling it or use a remote access solution that can be loaded as a system service rather than a user service so you can enter the PIN remotely. Wouldn't it be easier to just make it never sleep and leave it on 24/7? It's a "mini-PC" so it shouldn't use much power...

Comment: Some UNIX servers have a console on which you can logon and launch an `init x` command for starting the machine itself.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently abroad with a laptop and a new mini-PC. I'd like to get this mini-PC set up for remote use prior to my return to the USA where I will leave it and then hopefully use it when I return to Central America. I tried the WOL, following the guides and I just can't get it to work. Hence I thought I would look for alternatives. Re" the leaving it on 24/7, not worried about the power bill, just wasn't sure if doing that would wear the thing out or it would be more susceptible to hackers.

Comment: Leaving computers on is not the most wearing thing you can do to them. Also, note that the tag "wake-up" is specifically regarding "the transition of a computer from a sleeping or hibernated state to a normal operating state." which does not seem to be what you are asking. It may help your question get better attention to find tags that are more relevant to your specific use case.

Comment: Finally, the standard method for doing this is Wake On LAN. While you mention this term in your question, you say you used "Wake On Lan programs", which is not really what WoL is. Your hardware needs to support this, first, because there aren't any programs listening for the "magic packet" that signals the WoL function, just the computer hardware, which then initiates the power on sequence. I recommend that you review these questions and the concept of Wake On LAN more carefully: https://superuser.com/search?q=wake+on+lan

Comment: Also note that Wake On LAN is designed to work on LAN. I routinely `ssh` via Internet to a certain remote router (running OpenWrt, always on) and `etherwake` a "big" PC from it via their LAN. The (wired) network card of the PC has been configured to turn the whole rig on.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if you can get WoL ready, it may be that now your computer suddenly keeps powering on after you put it to hibernation. It is better to configure the pc to always power on if a power loss is detected, and use a smart plug that you can remotely toggle off and on. Much more reliable.